# Expo eas android build error: cannot copy 'C:\Users\xxx' to a subdirectory or itself,

Tags: expo

I get this error when i use this line:
`eas build -p android`
I am trying to build the project but it gives this error:

```
    Error: Cannot copy 'C:\Users\xx' to a subdirectory of itself,
    'C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\5897d1cd-52ae-4c3c-a5c4-577
    69487c9f8-shallow-clone'
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer may be late but I came across this in assisting a fellow dev and think I can answer this for other devs in the future at least.

So, EAS has integration capabilities with git. What that means is that for instance, when running a build command, EAS uploads a shallow clone of your repository to EAS Build. This error will come up when you do not have git setup on your machine or your project has no remote base that you're working off of.

There is a solution to disable the git integration ability for your project if you so wish. That is setting the environment variable `EAS_NO_VCS=1` So when running your build command, do this instead:

Mac: `EAS_NO_VCS=1 eas <command>`

Windows: `npx cross-env EAS_NO_VCS=1 eas <command>`

Reference: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-vcs-workflow.md

Hope this helps.